# How do large tap counts effect FIR Filters for block data?

Tags: fft, finite-impulse-response, delay, group-delay, arm

I am using the ARM CMSIS DSP library for a signal processing application. I find good filter performance when using tap counts that are in excess of 10% of the length of my data block. I understand that the tap count necessitates a delay in the output of the signal.

Does that imply that the first TAP_COUNT values of the filter result should be discarded? What would the result of using an FIR filter with a tap count of 50% or 99% of my data block be? Which would imply most of the output values are in the delay period? Should I zero pad my block data to compensate for the group delay?

Let me also add that post filtering I do an FFT and I'm not interested in time domain data.

**Edit**

System Flow:

1. N samples are collected as 32 bit floating point decimals in a buffer X.
2. X is filtered and decimated by M in a combined operation to a second memory of size N, Y. N / M samples are stored in Y each time this step is performed. For example if N = 64 and M = 4, 16 samples are stored in Y after the filter and decimate. This operation is implemented with https://arm-software.github.io/CMSIS_5/DSP/html/group__FIR__decimate.html.
3. After step 2 is performed M times, there are now M values in Y. The system takes the FFT(Y).

Step 2 exists to A) reduce memory usage and B) prevent aliasing into the Y data which might otherwise occur due to the sample rate reduction.

**EDIT II**

I'm including an image below that shows the difference between a 10 tap filter and a 101 tap filter on a sine wave, with the output from the ARM CMSIS FIR_F32 function. The difference in delays is quite apparent. Another way to phrase my question is that at what point does this begin to alter the frequency domain character of the signal being filtered? My gut sense is that negative effects begin to arise once the delay window is wide enough to bury anything periodic within the data block, basically half the block data length?

[image]

Comment: Do you understand what the *group delay* of a filter is? Also, what size is the FFT that you do after filtering? Are you sure you don't want to implement filtering in the frequency domain? What is the purpose of your filter? Would a cyclic convolution work for you as well?

Comment: Maybe not. The FFT is the same size as the block of data through the filter, 1024.  The filter is to prevent aliasing before down sampling the data. I think I want to implement the filter in the time domain since the process is occurring in real time and I need to filter before decimation and FFT. I'm not sure if a cylic convolution would work, I need to do more reading.

Comment: OK; to be honest, this suggests you're doing something you probably shouldn't: The real-time-ness of your problem can't be helped at all by a time-domain filter, if in the same signal chain you have an FFT, which needs samples "en bloc" anyway. If you do the filter in time domain (there might still be arguments for that!), you'd combine it with the decimation and get a massive decrease in computational load by not calculating output you'd be "decimating away" anyway. I think it would be very good if you could describe your full signal chain from "here the samples enter the system" to

Comment: "here the samples leave the system", including the *purpose* of the steps, *especially* the FFT: decimating and then doing an FFT does sound reasonable, *but* knowing that a > 100 tap filter can itself be more efficiently be implemented with FFTs, the question really is whether you couldn't "flip" the whole architecture and make your life easier.

Comment: Yes. I am using the combined CMSIS Filter - decimate function, so I acknowledge the cost savings by not filtering and decimating separately. Signal flow: 1) N samples are collected as 32-bit floats 2) N samples are filtered and decimated by M with FIR-filter-decimate of ~125 taps 3) After M successive executions of 1 & 2, FFT on result of 2 -- which now holds N points at the lower sample rate. The signal enters at 1 and leaves at 3. Step 2 is to prevent aliasing due to the sample rate reduction and reduce memory use. 
https://arm-software.github.io/CMSIS_5/DSP/html/group__FIR__decimate.html

Comment: This is getting really hard to follow, I know I'm asking much, but could you add this, structuredly, to your question by editing it, instead of as an answer, please?

Comment: Certainly, one minute.

Comment: Thank you very much!